# Node JS ignores undefined check

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, facebook-graph-api, https

Im working on a NodeJs app that takes an event from FB and puts it into a local database. For every event in the first page of the api query this goes well, except for the last one.

I am getting the following error:

> [December 1st 2016, 1:48:39 pm] TypeError: Cannot read property 'name'
>   of undefined
>       at IncomingMessage. (/home/node/virgo/app.js:217:32)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
>       at _stream_readable.js:907:16
>       at process._tickCallback (node.js:372:11)

Just after

```
console.log(resultBody);
```

Code:

```
function addFBEvent(facebookId){
console.log("getting event: " + facebookId);

var options = {
    hostname: 'graph.facebook.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/v2.8/'+facebookId+'?fields=name,description,start_time,end_time,place,photos{images}&access_token={INSERT API ACCESS CODE HERE}',
    method: 'GET'
};

https.request(options, function(res2) {
    var resultBody = "";
    res2.setEncoding('utf8');
    res2.on('data', function (chunk) {
        resultBody = resultBody + chunk;
    });

    res2.on('end', function () {
        dbConnection = sql.createConnection({
                                host     : settings.dbHost,
                                user     : settings.dbUser,
                                password : settings.dbPassword
                            });

        dbConnection.connect(function(err){
                if(!err) {
                    console.log("Database is connected ... nn");
                } else {
                    console.log("Error connecting database ... nn");
                }
        });

        var json = JSON.parse(resultBody);

        console.log(resultBody);

        if (json != undefined){
            var eventName = json.name;
            var eventStart = json.start_time;
            var eventEnd = json.end_time;
            var eventDescription = json.description;
            var eventPlace = json.place.name;
            var eventPoster = json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images[0].source;
            var eventId = json.id;

            console.log("name: " + eventName + ", start: " + eventStart + ", end: " + eventEnd + ", place: " + eventPlace + ", Poster: " + eventPoster);
            //console.log("Description: " + eventDescription);

            dbConnection.query('INSERT INTO SVVirgo.activities(title, description, image, start, end, price, location, facebook) VALUES ("'+eventName+'","'+eventDescription+'","'+eventPoster+'","'+eventStart+'","'+eventEnd+'",0,"'+eventPlace+'","'+eventId+'")', function (err, result){

            });
        }

        dbConnection.end();
    })
}).end();
}
```

See graph api explorer for the breaking event: [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=1682486658666506%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cdescription%2Cstart_time%2Cend_time%2Cplace%2Cphotos%7Bimages%7D&version=v2.8)

Event code: 1682486658666506

I've tried catching the undefined json object with no luck, i've also tried to validate the json using this solution: [Stackoverflow validate JSON javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3710204/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-json-string-in-javascript-without-using-try/3710226)

Comment: I updated my answer with more info.

Comment: It's correctly checking for undefined but you're getting an error here `var eventPlace = json.place.name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `https.request` try using [`request`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request).

It will give you parsed JSON and you won't have to do it manually.

If you want to do it manually like you do, then remember to wrap `var json = JSON.parse(resultBody);` in a try/catch block (or use [`tryjson`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tryjson)) because the `JSON.parse` cannot be used on unknown data outside of a try/catch - it can throw exceptions.

Another thing, don't open you database connection in your route handlers. You should open the connection once and just use it in your handlers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888459/using-mongodb-in-express-routers/40888709#40888709) for more info about it.

Right now you are connecting to the database but you continue outside of the connection callback, so you run all the lines beginning from `var json = JSON.parse(resultBody);` **before** the DB connection is established.

Additionally, the error may be not because `json` is undefined but because `json.place` is undefined.

You can change this:

```
var eventPlace = json.place.name;
```

to this:

```
var eventPlace = json.place && json.place.name;
```

You must also check `json.photos` before you access `json.photos.data` and test if `json.photos.data` is an array before you treat it as such (you can do it with:

```
if (json.photos && Array.isArray(json.photos.data)) {
  // ...
}
```

Basically, you need to make sure the values are what you want them to be before you access them. For example accessing this:

```
json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images[0].source
```

can fail when `json` is undefined, when `json.photos` is undefined, when `json.photos.data` is undefined, when `json.photos.data` is not an array, when `json.photos.data.length` is zero, when `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1]` is undefined, when `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images` is undefined, when `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images` is not an array, when `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images` is an array but it's empty, or when `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images` is a non-empty array but `json.photos.data[json.photos.data.length-1].images[0].source` is undefined.

As you can see there are a lot of assumptions that you are doing here. When those assumptions are not met, the code will fail.

Comment: A lot of usefull information thank you, luckily i can work with some assumption on the data since we are the ones making the events on facebook. The place not being available was an anomaly and is not going to happen in future events. However, it might indeed be a smart thing to get some checks in place for human errors.