# mongodb failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb

my code below

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 for(let i = 0;i<600;i++)
 {

    let  db1 =  mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/abc');
    db1.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("error  = "+(i)+"  "+error +db1);
    });
    db1.on('close', function() {
        console.log("close  = "+(i)+"  "+db1);
    });
    db1.once('open', function() {
        "use strict";
        // db1.close();
    });
 }
```

I wanted to test mongodb ,the result is

```
error  = 364  MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect[object Object]
error  = 365  MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect[object Object]
error  = 385  MongoError: failed to connect to server [127.0.0.1:27017] on first connect[object Object].......
```

Another question is whether the connection needs to be closed?
thanks.

Comment: are you sure that mongod process is running when you execute your app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that you have Mongo running on on port 27017 of the same computer that your Node app is running. To verify that, run this in the command line:

```
mongo localhost:27017
```

You don't need to close the connection and open it multiple times. You should open the connection once in your app and close it only when you want to close your app. See those answers for more datails:

- **[Where to initialize a new database connection in nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41324442/where-to-initialize-a-new-database-connection-in-nodejs/41325371#41325371)**
- **[Using mongoDB in Express routers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888459/using-mongodb-in-express-routers/40888709#40888709)**